# How to create html code when click button?

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-click

My code html code as the following :

```
<comp:Tab runat="server" ID="AddhocKPIs" ClientIDMode="Static" name="AddhocKPIs" label="Add Ad hoc KPI">
                            <table class="kpi-editor-layout">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="layout-column" style="border: 1px solid #eeeeee;">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row"></tr>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row">
                                                    <th>KPI Name</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" maxlength="30" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row">
                                                    <th>KPI Type</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select class="form-control" id="">
                                                            <option value="0">Numeric</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Percentage</option>
                                                            <option value="2">NonNumeric</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row">
                                                    <th>Precision</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="layout-column" style="border: 1px solid #eeeeee;">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row"></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>QRY</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td title="Query">
                                                        <select class="form-control" id="PmTabQueries">
                                                            <option value="{{QRY.Name}}" ng-repeat="QRY in PmTabQueries">{{QRY.Name}} ({{QRY.QRY}})</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="formula" colspan="3">
                                                        <div id="" class="FormulaEditor">
                                                            <div class="head form-inline" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                                <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="ui-autocomplete-input form-control clearfix" autocomplete="off" style="width: calc(100% - 45px);" />
                                                                <button title="Zoom In" id="zoomIn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only zoomInOut" role="button" ng-click="zoomInOutQRY()">
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span>
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-text">Zoom In</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                <button title="Zoom Out" id="zoomOut" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only zoomInOut" role="button" ng-click="zoomInOutQRY()">
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-text">Zoom Out</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                <div class="body" id="formulaContainer">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="body">
                                                                <iframe class="ui-widget-content formula" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                                                <iframe class="ui-widget-content formula-complete-popup" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </comp:Tab>
```

and I have a button. Code like this :

```
<button id="UxAddHocKPIs" class="ui-state-default inlineIconAddHoc" ng-click="addHocKPIs()">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Add new Ad hoc KPI</span>
            </button>
```

and this is my .js code (ng-click) :

```
$scope.addHocKPIs = function () {
                    console.log("a");
                }
```

I want to something like this: When I click addHocKPIs button, I should create html code again.

I mean,[image]

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qt2NpkwSnOhdbnTWRiFG?p=preview) for complete code.

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.current = 0;
  $scope.addHocKPIs = function () {
                    $scope.repeatTable.push('test'+$scope.current+1);
                };

  $scope.repeatTable= [];
   $scope.repeatTable.push('test'+$scope.current+1);
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="kpi-editor-layout" ng-repeat="tab in repeatTable track by $index">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="layout-column" style="border: 1px solid #eeeeee;">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row"></tr>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row">
                                                    <th>KPI Name</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" maxlength="30" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row">
                                                    <th>KPI Type</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select class="form-control" id="">
                                                            <option value="0">Numeric</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Percentage</option>
                                                            <option value="2">NonNumeric</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row">
                                                    <th>Precision</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="layout-column" style="border: 1px solid #eeeeee;">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: table-row"></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>QRY</th>
                                                    <td class="sep">:</td>
                                                    <td title="Query">
                                                        <select class="form-control" id="PmTabQueries">
                                                            <option value="{{QRY.Name}}" ng-repeat="QRY in PmTabQueries">{{QRY.Name}} ({{QRY.QRY}})</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="formula" colspan="3">
                                                        <div id="" class="FormulaEditor">
                                                            <div class="head form-inline" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                                <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="ui-autocomplete-input form-control clearfix" autocomplete="off" style="width: calc(100% - 45px);" />
                                                                <button title="Zoom In" id="zoomIn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only zoomInOut" role="button" ng-click="zoomInOutQRY()">
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span>
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-text">Zoom In</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                <button title="Zoom Out" id="zoomOut" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only zoomInOut" role="button" ng-click="zoomInOutQRY()">
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>
                                                                    <span class="ui-button-text">Zoom Out</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                <div class="body" id="formulaContainer">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="body">
                                                                <iframe class="ui-widget-content formula" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                                                <iframe class="ui-widget-content formula-complete-popup" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

Comment: It is discouraged to have code only answers. Try providing some explanation to the code you added and updated.

Comment: @John, I appreciate for your feedback. I will provide explanation. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, and by the way welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score -1):

you can use append and html
jQuery append() Method

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnID").click(function(){
        $("#divID").append(" <div>Appended HTML</div>.");
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because I thought it was silly to provide a jQuery-answer to a question tagged angular.

Comment: i know only jquery